# wget: reading from a list with id numbers and urls

Tags: text, wget, directory

In a .txt file, I have 500 lines containing an id number and a website homepage URL, in the following way

```
id_345  http://www.example1.com
id_367  http://www.example2.org
...
id_10452 http://www.example3.net
```

Using wget and the -i option, I am trying to download recursively part of these websites, but I would like to store the files in a way that is linked with the id number (storing the files in a directory called like the id number, or - the best option, but i think the most difficult to achieve - storing the html content in a single txt file called like the id number) .
Unfortunataly, the option -i cannot read a file like the one that i am using.
How can link the websites content with their connected id?

Thanks

P.s.: I imagine that to do so I have to 'go out' from wget, and call it through a script. If so, please take into account that I am a newbie in this sector (just some python experience), and that in particular I am not yet able to understand the logic and the code in bash scripts: step by step explanations for dummies are therefore very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get site recursively** with `wget -P ... -r -l ...` in Python, with parallel processing ([gist is here](https://gist.github.com/wwwslinger/6567919)):

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess, re

def getSiteRecursive(id, url, depth=2):
  cmd =  "wget -P " + id + " -r -l " + str(depth) + " " + url
  subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

input_file = "site_list.txt"
jobs = []
max_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
with open(input_file) as f:
  for line in f:
    id_url = re.compile("\s+").split(line)
    if len(id_url) >= 2:
      try:
        print "Grabbing " + id_url[1] + " into " + id_url[0] + " recursively..."
        if len(jobs) >= max_jobs:
          jobs[0].join()
          del jobs[0]
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getSiteRecursive,args=(id_url[0],id_url[1],2,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
      except Exception, e:
        print "Error for " + id_url[1] + ": " + str(e)
        pass
  for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

**Get single page into named file** with Python:

```
import urllib2, re
input_file = "site_list.txt"
#open the site list file
with open(input_file) as f:
  # loop through lines
  for line in f:
    # split out the id and url
    id_url = re.compile("\s+").split(line)
    print "Grabbing " + id_url[1] + " into " + id_url[0] + ".html..."
    try:
      # try to get the web page
      u = urllib2.urlopen(id_url[1])
      # save the GET response data to the id file (appended with "html")
      localFile = open(id_url[0]+".html", 'wb+')
      localFile.write(u.read())
      localFile.close()
      print "got " + id_url[0] + "!"
    except:
      print "Could not get " + id_url[0] + "!"
      pass
```

Example site_list.txt:

```
id_345  http://www.stackoverflow.com
id_367  http://stats.stackexchange.com
```

Output:

```
Grabbing http://www.stackoverflow.com into id_345.html...
got id_345!
Grabbing http://stats.stackexchange.com into id_367.html...
got id_367!
```

Directory listing:

```
get_urls.py
id_345.html
id_367.html
site_list.txt
```

---

**And if you prefer command line or shell scripting,** you can use `awk` to read each line with the default splitting at spaces, pipe it to a loop and execute with the backtick:

```
awk '{print "wget -O " $1 ".html " $2}' site_list.txt | while read line ; do `$line` ; done
```

### Breakdown...

```
awk '{print "wget -O " $1 ".html " $2}' site_list.txt |
```

- Use the `awk` tool to read each line of the site_list.txt file and
  split each line at spaces (default) into variables (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`,
  etc.), so that your id is in `$1` and your url is in `$2`.
- Add the `print` AWK command to construct the call for `wget`.
- Add the pipe operator `|` to send the output to the next command

Next we do the `wget` call:

```
while read line ; do `$line` ; done
```

- Loop through the prior command output line by line, storing it into the `$line` variable, and execute it using the backtick operator to interpret the text and run it as a command

Comment: I think that the first solution in Python is very useful, except for one thing: I am using wget because wget has the option -r to download also pages connected with the given url to a determined depth. as far as i know, this is much more difficult to obtain with every python module that i met. I will try immediately the second solution. In the meanwhile: it is possible to include somehow wget in the python program (instead than urllib2) or the two world are not easy to mix?

Comment: The second solution works perfectly. I slightly modified the code in this way:  `awk '{print "wget -P " $1 " " $2 "-r -l 2"}' lista.txt` . In this way I obtain a directory called like the id, with a large portion of the website inside. I apologize, maybe I was not clear enough in the question, my problem was in a case of recursive websites download, not with single urls (where, of course, Python works very well). wwwslinger, so my last and final question is: can i integrate wget in the python script you wrote?

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example in Python to use the recursive `wget` (and in parallel since the recursive `wget` will take a while).

Comment: Thank you very much. At the end, the linux solution worked smoothly, but it is useful to know that wget can be integrated in python in that way.